# Mysql keyring_file not loading

Tags: mysql, encryption, mysql8

I am trying to encrypt some tables in a mysql database. I found a way in Mysql documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html)

I have added the following lines under [mysqld] in my.cnf file

`early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so`

`keyring_file_data=/home/aneeez/keyring_my`

keyring_file.so exists in /usr/lib/mysql/plugin.
I have also created the file /home/aneeez/keyring_my

After restarting mysql, I executed following query, but got no results

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
   WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%'
```

And when I execute the query, `ALTER TABLE users ENCRYPTION = 'Y';` I'm getting the following error.

> #3185 - Can't find master key from keyring, please check in the server log if a keyring plugin is loaded and initialized successfully.
> Open new phpMyAdmin window

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Mysql error log below

> 2021-03-20T05:40:26.836746Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011370] [Server] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'File '/home/anees/keyring_my' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)'
> 2021-03-20T05:40:26.836801Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011355] [Server] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'
> 2021-03-20T05:40:26.836836Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010202] [Server] Plugin 'keyring_file' init function returned error.
> 2021-03-20T05:40:26.839667Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
> 2021-03-20T05:40:27.605193Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
> 2021-03-20T05:40:27.743091Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
> 2021-03-20T05:40:27.852035Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
> 2021-03-20T05:40:27.852667Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
> 2021-03-20T05:40:27.896459Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
> 2021-03-20T05:47:53.332801Z 59 [ERROR] [MY-012661] [InnoDB] Encryption can't find master key, please check the keyring plugin is loaded.
> 2021-03-20T06:22:48.430044Z 71 [ERROR] [MY-012656] [InnoDB] Encryption can't find master key, please check the keyring plugin is loaded. ret=1
> 2021-03-20T07:07:54.878488Z 107 [ERROR] [MY-012661] [InnoDB] Encryption can't find master key, please check the keyring plugin is loaded.

It says "File '/home/anees/keyring_my' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)" but the file exists

Comment: What relevant information is in the logs ?

Comment: @user620588 I have updated the question with the error log contents

Comment: You should read the log yourself, it really does tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @user620588 I did read the log. It says the keyring_file_data file file given is missing. But the file does exist and I've even changed the permissions but it didn't work. I commented that line and now it's working.

Comment: Perhaps then you should learn some more about file permissions. In particular pay attention to the directory path permissions.